# the line is not in a smooth curve in cesium when creating an animation line from the source to the destination

Tags: cesium

I have a task which I  want to create an animation line from the source to the destination.
I made 3 entities which are the source point, destination point and animation line.
The source is created by using the latitude and longitude including the destination point.
 When I run the the html file, I noticed that the line is not curve. Let me show you an image below.
[image]
Is there any way to make the line a smooth curve?

This is my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Use correct character set. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <script src="../Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <style>
      @import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
      html, body, #cesiumContainer {
          width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
    <script>
    //Configuration for latiude and longitude and flat mode
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

    var entities = viewer.entities;
    var scene = viewer.scene;
    scene.mode= Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D;
    var offSetLatitude =  '26.3351';//15.290270
    var offsetLongitude = '17.2283';//85.85195
    var target = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(offsetLongitude, offSetLatitude);
    var zoom = "42300000";
    viewer.camera.lookAt(target, new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, zoom ));
    //End of the configuration

    var sourceLongitude = 103.856;
    var sourceLatitude = 1.2931;
    var destinationLongitude = -71.0843;
    var destinationLatitude = 42.3626;
    var start = Cesium.JulianDate.now();
    var duration = 5;
    var sourceCountry = "Singapore";
    var destCountry = "United States";

    var startPoint = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(sourceLongitude, sourceLatitude);
    var finalPoint = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(destinationLongitude, destinationLatitude);
    // Calculate the midPoint to form the arc out of the earth surface
    var geodesic = new Cesium.EllipsoidGeodesic(startPoint, finalPoint);
    var midPoint = geodesic.interpolateUsingFraction(0.5, new Cesium.Cartographic());
    // Different heights for each attack polyline (1000000 ~ 5000000)
    var rand = [Math.floor((Math.random() * 700000) + 500000)];
    midPoint.height = rand;
    var positions = computePositions(startPoint, midPoint, finalPoint, start, duration);


    var target = viewer.entities.add({
        name: (sourceCountry + " - " + destCountry),
        position: positions,
        orientation: new Cesium.VelocityOrientationProperty(positions),
        path: {
            resolution: 0.3,
            material: new Cesium.PolylineGlowMaterialProperty({
                glowPower: 0.1,
                color: Cesium.Color.YELLOW
            }),
            width: 8,
            trailTime: duration,
            leadTime: 0
        }
    });


    target.position.setInterpolationOptions({

            interpolationDegree : 5,
            interpolationAlgorithm : Cesium.LagrangePolynomialApproximation 
    });

    var sourcePoint = viewer.entities.add({
                        name: sourceCountry,
                        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(sourceLongitude, sourceLatitude),
                        point : {
                                pixelSize : 5,
                                color : new Cesium.CallbackProperty(
                                function(time, result){
                                    return Cesium.Color.fromAlpha(Cesium.Color.RED);
                                }, false),
                            outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                            outlineWidth: 2
                        }
                    });

    var sourcePoint1 = viewer.entities.add({
                        name: sourceCountry,
                        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(sourceLongitude, sourceLatitude-5),
                        label : {
                                text : sourceCountry,
                                font : '10px Helvetica',
                                fillColor: Cesium.Color.SKYBLUE,
                                outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                                outlineWidth: 2
                        }
                    });

    /*
    var destPoint = viewer.entities.add({
                        name: destCountry,
                        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(destinationLongitude, destinationLatitude),
                        point : {
                                pixelSize : 5,
                                color : new Cesium.CallbackProperty(
                                function(time, result){
                                    return Cesium.Color.fromAlpha(Cesium.Color.YELLOW);
                                }, false),
                            outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                            outlineWidth: 2
                        }
                    });
    */
        var destPoint = viewer.entities.add({
                        name: destCountry,
                        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(destinationLongitude, destinationLatitude),
                        point : {
                            pixelSize: 5,
                            color: Cesium.Color.PINK,
                            outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                            outlineWidth: 2
                        }
                    });
        var destPoint1 = viewer.entities.add({
                        name: destCountry,
                        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(destinationLongitude, destinationLatitude-5),
                        label : {
                                text : destCountry,
                                font : '10px Helvetica',
                                fillColor: Cesium.Color.SKYBLUE,
                                outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                                outlineWidth: 2
                        }
                    });


    function computePositions(startPoint, midPoint, finalpoint, startTime, duration) {

        var property = new Cesium.SampledPositionProperty();

        var startPosition = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(startPoint);
        property.addSample(startTime, startPosition);

        var midTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(startTime, duration/2, new Cesium.JulianDate());
        var midPosition = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(midPoint);
        property.addSample(midTime, midPosition);

        var endTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(startTime, duration, new Cesium.JulianDate());
        var endPosition = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(finalPoint);
        property.addSample(endTime, endPosition);
        return property;
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  The linked question is about polygons, this question is about polylines.  The two are not the same.

Comment: you've got `duration = 5` in your code here, and later you have an `entity.path` with `resolution: 1` (seconds).  This is likely why your path has only 5 sections in it.  Try increasing your duration, or decreasing your resolution.  Also, I can't get your code to run in the debug version of Cesium, you've got numbers inside quotes and Cesium is throwing type errors at me.  Typically you should develop against non-minified Cesium so that you can catch these errors.

Comment: You need to densify your lines, this is exactly the same as in the linked question.

Comment: It's similar in spirit, yes.  But the answers of the linked question all talk about putting smaller polygons closer together.  The correct answer here would talk about editing the `resolution` of a `path`, which is a different API in Cesium.

Comment: @emackey, you mention that you got errors in your code, but I do not receive any errors in the console.log

Comment: @IanTurton, can you elaborate more about densify the line.

Comment: @Based on the solution you have provided, I have decreased the resolution to 0.1, it works, it works, it travels in a very smooth curve.

Comment: i have attached the new image to show you

Comment: Thanks for the new image, glad it worked.  You should keep the original image in your question though, to preserve clarity of what you originally asked here.  We can attach the fixed image to an answer, if the [duplicate] flag is removed.